# Condtional XML to XML transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, transformation

I am struggling with a data transformation issuse and would really appreciate your help and advice.

I would like to transform a fairly large xml file into another xml format. My collegues tell me that using XSLT would solve my problem, however at first glance I find XSLT not being capable of doing the conditional formatting I need. As you can see from my xml under I need to derive a number of timeseries points from a specified timeinterval described in the start- and endtime tags.

My question is therefore what the best practice for such a problem? Is this easy solvable using XSLT, or using another technology? Or is this best handled writing custom code?

Looking forward for your answers.

Best regards!

XML to be transformed:

```
<starttime>
    <datetime>201605130500</datetime>
    <qualifier>163</Qualifier>
</starttime>
<endtime>
    <datetime>201605150500</datetime>
    <qualifier>164</Qualifier>
</endtime>
<seriesPeriod>
    <quantityDetails>
        <quantity>8.0</quantity>
        <qualifier>135</qualifier>
    </quantityDetails>
    <datetimeDetails>
        <datetime>201605130500201605130600</datetime> <!-- This is a period to from 05:00 to 06:00 (from-to YYYYMMDDHHH-YYYYMMDDHHH) -->
        <qualifier>324</qualifier>
    </datetimeDetails>
</seriesPeriod>
<seriesPeriod>
    <quantityDetails>
        <quantity>-11</quantity>
        <qualifier>135</qualifier>
    </quantityDetails>
    <datetimeDetails>
        <dateTime>201605130600201605130700</dateTime>
        <qualifier>324</qualifier>
    </datetimeDetails>  
</seriesPeriod>
<!-- Continues with a total of 48 similar "seriesPeriod", one point for each hour in the timeinterval derived from starttime and endtime -->
```

---

Expected result after transformation:

```
<timeseries>
    <timeinterval>
        <start>2016-05-13T05:00Z</start>
        <end>2016-05-15T05:00Z</end>
    </timeinterval>
    <point>
        <position>1</position>
        <quantity>8</quantity>
    </point>
    <point>
        <position>2</position>
        <quantity>-11</quantity>
    </point>
    <!-- Continues with a total of 48 similar "points", one point for each hour in the timeinterval -->
</timeseries>
```

Comment: XSLT could be a good tool for the task here, but you will need to explain the logic of your required transformation. In particular, where do the `quantity` values come from in your expected result? Thanks

Comment: An explanation of the logic - along with a more comprehensive (and well-formed!) example - would be useful. Also indicate if you can use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Please clearify how the quantity of "4" on the first point and "-11" on the second point is calculated.

Comment: A little mistake in my xml, sorry for the misunderstanding. I've updated the example so that the quantity is equal in both pre and post transformation. There was no logic behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. Especially the part about  "*conditional formatting*" - I don't see any conditions in your description.

FWIW, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <timeseries>
        <timeinterval>
            <start>
                <xsl:call-template name="format-as-date">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="starttime/datetime"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </start>
            <end>
                <xsl:call-template name="format-as-date">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="endtime/datetime"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </end>
        </timeinterval>
        <xsl:for-each select="seriesPeriod">
            <point>
                <position>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </position>
                <quantity>
                    <xsl:value-of select="number(quantityDetails/quantity)"/>
                </quantity>
            </point>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </timeseries>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="format-as-date">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 5, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 7, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 9, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 11, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>Z</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the following well-formed (!) input:

**XML**

```
<root>
  <starttime>
    <datetime>201605130500</datetime>
    <qualifier>163</qualifier>
  </starttime>
  <endtime>
    <datetime>201605150500</datetime>
    <qualifier>164</qualifier>
  </endtime>  
  <seriesPeriod>
    <quantityDetails>
      <quantity>8.0</quantity>
      <qualifier>135</qualifier>
    </quantityDetails>
    <datetimeDetails>
      <datetime>201605130500201605130600</datetime>
      <qualifier>324</qualifier>
    </datetimeDetails>
  </seriesPeriod>
  <seriesPeriod>
    <quantityDetails>
      <quantity>-11</quantity>
      <qualifier>135</qualifier>
    </quantityDetails>
    <datetimeDetails>
      <dateTime>201605130600201605130700</dateTime>
      <qualifier>324</qualifier>
    </datetimeDetails>
  </seriesPeriod>
</root>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<timeseries>
   <timeinterval>
      <start>2016-05-13T05:00Z</start>
      <end>2016-05-15T05:00Z</end>
   </timeinterval>
   <point>
      <position>1</position>
      <quantity>8</quantity>
   </point>
   <point>
      <position>2</position>
      <quantity>-11</quantity>
   </point>
</timeseries>
```

which is identical to your expected result - either by design, or by coincidence.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael! I am very new to XSLT so this is helping me a lot in my learning. What I meant by conditional formatting was that I thought I would have to derive the position numbering from the start- and endtime as I was not aware of 'value-of select="position()'.

Comment: "*I thought I would have to derive the position numbering from the start- and endtime*" That would have been an "interesting" problem...